# Python matplotlib format

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, graph, scatter

My python program is producing a graph that is stacked with each other. I want to automatically use the next page if the matplotlib scatter plot is already stacked with each other

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt


def countWords(file):
    plt.style.use("seaborn")
    x = []
    y = []
    words = {}
    i = 0
    for line in file:
        w = line.split(" ")  # output list
        for b in line.split():
            words[b] = words.get(b, 0) + 1

        for w, c in words.items():
            plt.scatter(w, c, cmap="Greens",edgecolors="black",alpha=0.75,linewidths=1)
    plt.locator_params(axis="both", integer=True, tight=False)
    plt.xlabel("Words")
    plt.ylabel("Number of Occurrence")
    
    plt.show()


file = open("mytext.txt", "r")
print(countWords(file))
```

[image: This is the sample image]

[mytext.txt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ij5jt.png)

Comment: Can you show us what `mytext.txt` looks like or provide a sample of the file? Although your question might be able to be answered by recreating a similar data set from inspecting your scatter plot, it would help toward making your question more reproducible

Comment: noted on this. Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

To reduce the amount of words on the x-axis, you can split your `words` `dict` and create multiple figures/charts and save them locally. Those images can be imported by Microsoft Word or LibreOffice to create a page. You can also [rotate](https://www.datasciencelearner.com/matplotlib-rotate-x-axis-labels/) them to save space. It is possible to change the figure and the text size.

Also, why do you need a scatter plot? There are (stacked/grouped) bar charts (see https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/index.html#).

I recommend opening files using the `with` statement (see https://thispointer.com/python-open-a-file-using-open-with-statement-benefits-explained-with-examples/).